# Setting time left in a cookie so it doesn't start counting again after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

my problem is : I have created this page using countdown plugin, but the thing is it starts counting again every time i refresh the page, and I need it to remember the time left and not start again. I have seen several posts about this, explaining that it should be done trough usage of cookies, but I couldn't figure it out....
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

jquery:

```
 (function($){

    $.fn.countDown = function (options) {

        config = {};

        $.extend(config, options);

        diffSecs = this.setCountDown(config);

        if (config.onComplete)
        {
            $.data($(this)[0], 'callback', config.onComplete);
        }
        if (config.omitWeeks)
        {
            $.data($(this)[0], 'omitWeeks', config.omitWeeks);
        }

        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .digit').html('<div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div>');
        $(this).doCountDown($(this).attr('id'), diffSecs, 500);

        return this;

    };

    $.fn.stopCountDown = function () {
        clearTimeout($.data(this[0], 'timer'));
    };

    $.fn.startCountDown = function () {
        this.doCountDown($(this).attr('id'),$.data(this[0], 'diffSecs'), 500);
    };

    $.fn.setCountDown = function (options) {
        var targetTime = new Date();

        if (options.targetDate)
        {
            targetTime = new Date(options.targetDate.month + '/' + options.targetDate.day + '/' + options.targetDate.year + ' ' + options.targetDate.hour + ':' + options.targetDate.min + ':' + options.targetDate.sec + (options.targetDate.utc ? ' UTC' : ''));
        }
        else if (options.targetOffset)
        {
            targetTime.setFullYear(options.targetOffset.year + targetTime.getFullYear());
            targetTime.setMonth(options.targetOffset.month + targetTime.getMonth());
            targetTime.setDate(options.targetOffset.day + targetTime.getDate());
            targetTime.setHours(options.targetOffset.hour + targetTime.getHours());
            targetTime.setMinutes(options.targetOffset.min + targetTime.getMinutes());
            targetTime.setSeconds(options.targetOffset.sec + targetTime.getSeconds());
        }

        var nowTime = new Date();

        diffSecs = Math.floor((targetTime.valueOf()-nowTime.valueOf())/1000);

        $.data(this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);

        return diffSecs;
    };

    $.fn.doCountDown = function (id, diffSecs, duration) {
        $this = $('#' + id);
        if (diffSecs <= 0)
        {
            diffSecs = 0;
            if ($.data($this[0], 'timer'))
            {
                clearTimeout($.data($this[0], 'timer'));
            }
        }

        secs = diffSecs % 60;
        mins = Math.floor(diffSecs/60)%60;
        hours = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60)%24;
        if ($.data($this[0], 'omitWeeks') == true)
        {
            days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24);
            weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
        }
        else 
        {
            days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24)%7;
            weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
        }

        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'seconds_dash', secs, duration ? duration : 800);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'minutes_dash', mins, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'hours_dash', hours, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'days_dash', days, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'weeks_dash', weeks, duration ? duration : 1200);

        $.data($this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);
        if (diffSecs > 0)
        {
            e = $this;
            t = setTimeout(function() { e.doCountDown(id, diffSecs-1) } , 1000);
            $.data(e[0], 'timer', t);
        } 
        else if (cb = $.data($this[0], 'callback')) 
        {
            $.data($this[0], 'callback')();
        }

    };

    $.fn.dashChangeTo = function(id, dash, n, duration) {
          $this = $('#' + id);

          for (var i=($this.find('.' + dash + ' .digit').length-1); i>=0; i--)
          {
                var d = n%10;
                n = (n - d) / 10;
                $this.digitChangeTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash + ' .digit:eq('+i+')', d, duration);
          }
    };

    $.fn.digitChangeTo = function (digit, n, duration) {
        if (!duration)
        {
            duration = 800;
        }
        if ($(digit + ' div.top').html() != n + '')
        {

            $(digit + ' div.top').css({'display': 'none'});
            $(digit + ' div.top').html((n ? n : '0')).slideDown(duration);

            $(digit + ' div.bottom').animate({'height': ''}, duration, function() {
                $(digit + ' div.bottom').html($(digit + ' div.top').html());
                $(digit + ' div.bottom').css({'display': 'block', 'height': ''});
                $(digit + ' div.top').hide().slideUp(10);


            });
        }
    };



})(jQuery);
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/misc.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css"></link>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
    <h2>SPECIJALNA </br>PONUDA</h2>
    <img src="images/top.png" style="float:left;padding-left:15px;">
        <div id="top_offer">
                <p>Registrujte se u narednih 60 sekundi i ostvarite pravo na ekskluzivni set za edukaciju + sastanak 1 na 1 sa Vašim ličnim expertom!</p>
            </div>
        <!-- Countdown dashboard start -->
        <div id="countdown_dashboard">


            <div class="dash minutes_dash">
                <span class="dash_title"></span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

            <div class="dash seconds_dash">
                <span class="dash_title"></span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Countdown dashboard end -->


        <div class="info_message" id="complete_info_message">
            <a href="http://bit.ly/10iXl5L" target="_blank"> <img src="images/offer.png" /> <p>Klikni ovde ► </p></a>
        </div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            // Set the Countdown
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
        targetOffset: {
            'day':      0,
            'month':    0,
            'year':     0,
            'hour':     0,
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      60
        }, 
        // onComplete function
        onComplete: function() { 
        $('#container').slideUp(); }
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.cookie('mytimeout', setTimeout, {
        expires: 1,
        path: '/'
    });
    };
});
        </script>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI, I'd store target time rather than remaining time, so that if a page load is delayed (or fails), you don't end up with a gap in the timing

Comment: What exactly couln't you figure out? How to create and read a cookie with Jquery?

Comment: nope, how to store remaining time. I am using jquery cookie plugin.

Comment: Follow the advise of adam. His way is easier than yours. Store the date in milliseconds.